# Chrome DevTools: Slow frames, but no events causing them

Tags: performance, google-chrome, rendering, google-chrome-devtools

What does it mean, when you have slow frames (those ones indicated with red triangles) in Chrome Dev Tools' Timeline, but it doesn't show what causes that (script, render, composition, etc). It's like nothing really happens but you still have janks.

[image: Chrome DevTools Timeline view]

Comment: Could it be a garbage collection?

Comment: My assumption is that this is the performance tool itself blocking on IO due to sending data needed to provide the information presented in the performance view. It simply hides this from view as it doesn't make sense to performance test the performance tool itself. When it happened with me it was when I was perf testing an Android device so it had to send the debug information over USB for each frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the time-span above the main thread, and then click on the Bottom-Up tab at the bottom, you can see all the individual activities going on that add up to that total time. I suspect there must be some other activities you can't currently see, but if you scroll vertically, you should see them - probably `Rasterize Paint` on another worker.

[image: Timeline]

**Update**
I realised that the times in the Bottom-Up view do not add up to the total time shown for the frame. I did a little more playing and it looks as though the remaining time is 'Idle' time.

If you look at the screenshot below, I have adjusted the Timeline view to contain approximately one frame that has very minimal activity. It's a little bit more than one frame because you can see the dotted lines on either side are a little further in.

If you then look at the bottom Summary view, you can see the majority of time is listed as 'Idle'. If you pretend I more accurately filtered the Timeline view to be exactly one frame (by taking off a tiny bit of time from the summary values), you could probably fairly confidently come to the conclusion that the total frame time (shown just above the Main Thread bar) is the summation of the values shown in Summary, including the 'Idle' time.

[image: Network tab idle time]

Comment: The thing is that I either don't have any activities displayed within those "slow" frames or I have some of them but they take something like 0.1ms each whereas the frame takes ~32ms, that is what confuses me

Comment: @wizardzloy I have added an update to the post above.

Comment: Thanks again, that's awesome but my question is exactly about why it takes 32ms for a browser to process the frame if the majority of the time it doesn't do anything (Idle). Why do I have slow frame rate here?